# generic return type is not mapped by argument

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type a generic function which generic return value depends on argument type. Simplified code looks like this:

```js
type QueueFlushFailAction = {
  "duplicate-file-name": "open-existing-on-collision" | "remove-from-queue";
  "no-connection": "reconnect" | "continue";
};

type FileFlushFailCallback = <T extends keyof QueueFlushFailAction>(
  file: any,
  error: T
) => Promise<QueueFlushFailAction[T]>;

const fileFlushFailCallback: FileFlushFailCallback = async (file, error) => {
  if (error === "duplicate-file-name") {
    if (file.exists) return "open-existing-on-collision";
    else return "remove-from-queue";
  }

  if (error === "no-connection") {
    if (file.retryCount < 3) return "reconnect";
    else return "continue";
  }

  return 'continue';
};
```

I get:

```
Type '<T extends keyof QueueFlushFailAction>(file: any, error: T) => Promise<"open-existing-on-collision" | "remove-from-queue" | "reconnect" | "continue">' is not assignable to type 'FileFlushFailCallback'.
  Type 'Promise<"open-existing-on-collision" | "remove-from-queue" | "reconnect" | "continue">' is not assignable to type 'Promise<QueueFlushFailAction[T]>'.
    Type '"open-existing-on-collision" | "remove-from-queue" | "reconnect" | "continue"' is not assignable to type 'QueueFlushFailAction[T]'.
      Type '"open-existing-on-collision"' is not assignable to type 'QueueFlushFailAction[T]'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAigrhBAxANnAzgCyQQwJYoCCAxsHgPYB2UAvFAN4CwAUFFAEQAmcYKexOYBAC0AMwIjKOALYR2ALg7lIlYRAAeedGUoBzYVWHFyKPugqV2UAD4cAThGnkAbiNF3y04QEcECdgDcLGzslORGVJQQpBYK9tGR0cBWtuzGlDr%20QcwAvtksoJBQSBKoGNj4KADCOKYARjjEANa0UAA8ACpQGkKUnOhQTRAg5KKwfhBlWLgEJGRUAHwAFMFQ4igQijiUIAA0qxB2HnaKHSwAlLQLUAAKHtJaEG3wiJNo05VzFgDaHQC6C3yzHS2jWpXeFQINXqjSaihKGymkOqtRQDWarRw6BAlGIUCW6wgu26R3IdkuNGuTFYUDwYyWh2OtBodC4PD4AiEYgkwiksnYl2pbDYdPxhIAdBotMB0JcHMA4HZqOxlBBVFLtHg9AZVMZTFpYtlhd0UOhoPLFcqHE5XGJ7j4JoFVjkWKtRQzSXZmaywhFKFEYlQBQxViL6RL5XYQFVyHAMu0oABmOUQBVK%20LpAPJI3CiCm82py0cdKZOQ5l3MVYW9MAchLWoQNeyeRYQA)

Is there a type-safe way to type it using generics or some other mechanism?

I know similar can be achieved using function overloading, but `FileFlushFailCallback` type will be in the library and it's implementation in a lib-user code, while function overloading as I understand in typescript requires function implementation to be in the same file as the function declarations.

Comment: Nothing. TypeScript just can't reason about control flow with generics. One easy way to get around this would be to just use an assertion: https://tsplay.dev/w6QBvW

Comment: Is the question here truly just "what am I doing wrong"?  Or are you looking to fix it in some way, and if so, are you more interested in convenience or type safety?  For convenience, just assert.  For type safety, generic indexed accesses can only be verified via a generic indexing operation, so you can change the impl to be in that form, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WPMjzw).  I'd be happy to write up that latter thing as an answer, if you'd [edit] the question to clarify that you are actually looking for a compiler-verified type safe fix.

Comment: @jcalz i modified the question, yes I'm looking for a type-safe alternative to my code,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a value `error` of [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `K` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof QueueFlushFailAction`, the compiler is unfortunately not able to use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) (e.g., `if` or `switch`/`case`) to verify that you have a value of the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `QueueFlushFailAction[K]`.  There's an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) for such support, but for now it's not part of the language.

Right now the only way the compiler will be able to verify that you have a value of type `QueueFlushFailAction[K]` is if you actually give it a value of type `QueueFlushFailAction` and index into it with a key of type `K`.  Luckily it's fairly easy to refactor your implementation into such a form.  You can make a "lazy" instance of `QueueFlushFailAction` using [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```
const fileFlushFailCallback: FileFlushFailCallback =
  async (file, error) => {
    return {
      get "duplicate-file-name"() {
        if (file.exists) return "open-existing-on-collision";
        else return "remove-from-queue";
      },
      get "no-connection"() {
        if (file.retryCount < 3) return "reconnect";
        else return "continue";
      }
    }[error];
  }; // okay
```

This behaves very much like your version.  The compiler uses `error` as an index into some object.  This automatically dispatches to the appropriate getter method instead of looking for it via a series of `if` statements.  And only the appropriate getter method is evaluated.  Note that we don't need a bail-out `return 'continue'` line at the end either, since the previous line returns unconditionally.

Of course this isn't really idiomatic JavaScript, so you might decide to just to keep your original implementation and use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or the like to stop the compiler from complaining.  But then you're taking responsibility for the type safety instead of relying on the compiler to verify it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-VZ5FhAA)

Comment: thanks, finally was able to achieve what I need, however (forgot to write it in the question) getters might return promises so I had to refactor `QueueFlushFailAction ` as following `"duplicate-file-name": Promise<"open-existing-on-collision" | "remove-from-queue";>` and so on for the rest of the properties. Is there a cleaner way? Didn't get how can I await inside the `fileFlushFailCallback`

Comment: You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVrKlN) but I consider that out of scope for the question as asked.  If you have more questions after this I suggest you create a new question post for it.